# Bootstrap 4: Vertically center anything in the middle of form-group > input element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, is possible center any element vertically in the middle of input? (with a simple structure, not a lot of divs)

The first example of https://jsfiddle.net/fekula/8j4ew5df/9/ is more or less good, but the second and third bad

```
<div class="form-row align-items-end">
   <div class="form-group col-md-7">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label>
        Center text
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First label is not centered, it has just a bottom margin for default for labels without classes.
For example, by adding `mb-2` class to the `.custom-control.custom-switch` element hit the trick.

But you need to put your `input[type="text"]` in one `.row` element with labels to centering them verticaly.

Comment: I would like center vertically elements, without margins.